# Converting ADC value from wind direction sensor into degrees

Tags: python

I'm building a weather station using the raspberry pi and am trying to add the wind direction sensor (through a 12-bit ADS1015 analog to digital converter that I'm waiting to receive). I've looked around for some time on how to do this in python but was only able to get 1 piece of code working on an arduino, to convert raw values into actual wind directions, in degrees.

I now wish to do the same thing in python, on the raspberry pi.

Assuming I use a 12 bit ADC connected to 3.3 volts on the raspberry pi, how do I convert the raw signals from the ADC (gotten using `adc_value = adc.read_adc(1, gain = 1)` with the Adafruit library for the ADC) into actual wind directions in degrees? The analog voltage of the sensor ranges from 5% of the input voltage (indicating 0 degrees), to 95% of the input voltage (indicating 360 degrees). I'm not sure how to map them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of modeling in a spreadsheet, which is how I've derived linear mappings for such devices in the past.  Assumes linearity over the range:

[image]

Graph and table demonstrates a linear range varying from 5% to 95% of potential ADC values, per the datasheet.  After recording high and low points, I calculated the delta ADC per 20 degrees.  I then plotted them and included the linear trendline along with the resultant *y=mx+b* formula.  This is the conversion formula for raw ADC values (based on 3.3V) that you need to use.

Now, as to how to do this in python on the Pi, that's another matter.  The device you're using is an I2C device.  There are many tutorials on this topic.

1. First, you must enable I2C on Linux on the Pi, [for example](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIm-_-7_S-1QIVxGF-Ch2_Fw2bEAAYASAAEgIiSvD_BwE).
2. Consult an online tutorial on configuring and wiring the I2C device.  The datasheet on Digikey for your device is a great place to start.
3. Using the address you've selected with the pins, read the device using a python library widely available online, [for example](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO/blob/master/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py).

Comment: apologies for the late reply... thank you, this helps a lot! However, the one thing I'm trying to find out is the code for actually mapping the raw values from the analog pin to their equivalent wind directions in degrees like you've done with those in the table above. In other words, how can I calculate that excel spreadsheet in code, so I can translate to any value? I can read the sensor, I just don't know how to calculate the actual direction without looking in the table, which would only allow me to get 19 values as opposed to the total 360

Comment: ohh, I understand now. Thank you! None of this mildly complicated maths I've been seeing to calculate the value, just a simple division. One last thing, so I can update and check the code on the currently running arduino: what would I divide the ADC reading by to get degrees with the arduino's 10 bit ADC, running on 3.3 volts? Thanks again

Comment: That's odd, I divided the value of the ADC by 4 but when I spin the sensor, I only see values ranging from around 10 to around 199 degrees.

Comment: @HenryHunt What I would do in your case is to put aside the idea of degrees for a bit.  Focus on the ADC values that are returned.  Slowly rotate the sensor and see if they range from 0 to 1024, or what.  That's the first step, is to see exactly what's being reported.  Then we can update our model (formula) based on that.  May also want to update your question with the code you're using right now.

Comment: Okay, the range is from 32 to 637

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151143/discussion-between-tomservo-and-henryhunt).